# How to use Lambda to return Grouped array of Distinct rows

Tags: c#, lambda

I am trying to select rows from a table. I need to perform a GroupBy on one column and then execute Distinct() on a different column. I would like to return entire rows in the results.

Assuming a database table has the following structure and data:

```
GroupId = 1, To = "A", From = "B", Flag = True
GroupId = 1, To = "A", From = "C", Flag = True
GroupId = 1, To = "B", From = "A", Flag = True
GroupId = 1, To = "B", From = "C", Flag = False
GroupId = 1, To = "C", From = "A", Flag = True
GroupId = 1, To = "C", From = "B", Flag = True
GroupId = 2, To = "A", From = "B", Flag = True
GroupId = 2, To = "B", From = "C", Flag = True
GroupId = 2, To = "C", From = "A", Flag = True
GroupId = 2, To = "D", From = "C", Flag = True
GroupId = 2, To = "D", From = "A", Flag = False
GroupId = 2, To = "A", From = "B", Flag = True
```

The following line of code returns an array of Groups with each containing an array of `To` strings:

```
var test = db.LookupMap
    .Where(u => u.Flag == true)
    .GroupBy(u => u.GroupId, (key, group) => group.Select(m => m.To).Distinct())
    .ToArray();
```

I can get an array of objects by changing `m.To` to `m`:

```
.GroupBy(u => u.GroupId, (key, group) => group.Select(m => m).Distinct())
```

But this breaks Distinct() on the To column.

How can I return an array of objects (entire row) instead of an array strings?

Note: The To column should be distinct per unique GroupId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another `GroupBy` combined with `First`:

```
.GroupBy(u => u.GroupId,
        (key, group) => group.GroupBy(m => m.To).Select(g => g.First()))
```

It groups items without first group using `To` property value and then takes first item from every inner group. It's the easiest way to get something equivalent to `DistinctBy` method from moreLINQ - get whole row, but `Distinct` should run only on one property values.

Comment: your solution works great! I have a difficult time breaking down that line of code. It works, but I don't understand how it's doing it. Thank you.

Comment: I added a little more description. Hope it helps.